# Enlarge URLImage size

Tags: java, image, mobile, codenameone, urlimageviewhelper

I want know if there any possible way to enlarge URLImage size using codenameone

this is the code:
EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.createFromImage(theme.getImage("i.png"), false);
        URLImage urlim = URLImage.createToStorage(enc, "test"+a.getId(), "http://127.0.0.1/armes_details_images/usp.png");
        ImageViewer a1 = new ImageViewer(urlim);

Thank you for your help

Comment: you can set the size of the image viewer bigger, the size you want, and set to fill.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder image determines the size of the downloaded image. That means that if the download image doesn't match the placeholder size it will be scaled/cropped and there are various API's within `URLImage` to determine how that scaling/cropping behaves.

Notice that you can always scale an image on the device but if you scale an image which was already scaled you will degrade quality further as every scaling operation degrades quality.

You can download the image as a file using various tools at which point it will be in the full resolution and you can scale it to any size you want. E.g. `ConnectionRequest.downloadImageToStorage` could be more in line with what you want.